# Extracting nodes from an RSS file

Tags: php

I have used Google the last hour to try and find a soution, but i don't see anything coming up, what i'm doing is parsing ebay's RSS feed which for the most part is working.

RSS:

`http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=Laptop%20&campaignid=5338607813%20&sortOrder=BestMatch%20&programid=15`

My Function:

```
function parseEbayRSSFeed($url) {
    try {
        $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
        $res = [];
        foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
            $res[] = [
                'ebayLink' => $item->link,
                'ebayTitle' => $item->title,
                'ebayDescription' => $item->description
            ];
        }
        return $res;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();      
    }   
}
```

My function parses the link / title / description fine, but i cannot seem to parse the fields like:

```
<e:CurrentPrice>64.99</e:CurrentPrice>
```

I tried adding:

```
$res[] = [
    'ebayLink' => $item->link,
    'ebayTitle' => $item->title,
    'ebayDescription' => $item->description,
    'ebayPrice' => $item->e:CurrentPrice
     ];
```

But this produces the error:

`syntax error, unexpected ':'`

So the `:` is causing the issue somehow, any tips on how to fix would be great.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `var_dump($item)`?

Comment: Sure, i posted it here as it's quite big: https://pastebin.com/mcEWkCjX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CurrentPrice tag is under a [XML namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp), in the eBay example e = http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services, so you need to browse the tree with this namespace, like this :

```
$url = 'http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=Laptop%20&campaignid=5338607813%20&sortOrder=BestMatch%20&programid=15';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
$res = [];
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $res[] = [
        'ebayLink' => $item->link,
        'ebayTitle' => $item->title,
        'ebayDescription' => $item->description,
        'ebayPrice' => $item->children('http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services')->CurrentPrice,
    ];
}

print_r($res);
```

You can see the activation of the namespace with the [children](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

`<e:something>` is the children with a namespace of `item` so you have to get the children with that namespace first before accessing.

```
$url = "http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=Laptop%20&campaignid=5338607813%20&sortOrder=BestMatch%20&programid=15";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
$res = [];
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $e = $item->children('e', TRUE);
    $res[] = [
        'ebayLink' => $item->link,
        'ebayTitle' => $item->title,
        'ebayDescription' => $item->description,
        'ebayPrice' => $e->CurrentPrice
    ];
}
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Thank you, now i get it, reading up on children nodes, this is why my ``var_dump()`` never showed them, thank you again.